# Strange undefined jquery error

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to itterate trough a jquery array, and I am having an error
The script causing the error is:

```
$.each(amount, function (key, value) {
    console.info('>>> Selected line: '+value.value + " " + value.currency);
    if ((value.currency == currency) && (value.value == val)) {
        amount.splice(key,1);
        console.info('Deleted: [' + value.value + " " + value.currency+ "] from line "+ key);
    }
});
```

The error firebug throws is:

```
TypeError: value is undefined
```

Could someone point me where the error is or how to fix the error?

Comment: amount is an array by the form bellow:

Comment: [{value: 100, currency: 'EUR'}, {value: 125, currency: 'USD'}]

Comment: Did that also, and changed the function (key, value) to function (key, data) but still get the data is undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with your `.splice()`. When you remove item 0, everything moves up a spot, so you no longer have an item 1.

Generally speaking, you can't remove items from a list you're enumerating (unless taking steps to adjust the current index when adding or removing items, but.. yuck).

I would recommend using a filter function like grep instead:

http://jsfiddle.net/DnN4a/

```
var newArr = $.grep(amount, function(item, idx) {
   return item.currency == currency || item.value == val; 
}, true);
```

Comment: Thank you! I thaught that it could be related to changing the array, but had no clue about how to avoid splice